# Proving that $\lim_{x \to \infty}x \cos (1/x) = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}x \cos (1/x) = \infty$ using the epsilon delta definition of limit and without using any other theorem?

I tried so far but failed.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What is $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos (1/x)$ ? $\cos$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $x\gt \frac{3}{\pi}$, then $\cos(1/x)\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You are welcome. Let $B\gt 0$. I imagine that it is clear now that as long as $x$ is greater than the larger of $2B$ and $\frac{3}{\pi}$, we will have $x\cos(1/x)\gt B$.

Comment: Yes. Because if $M \geq 3/(2 \pi)$ we can take $N = 2*M$ and if $M < 3/(2 \pi)$ we can choose $N=3/ \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** as $\lim_0 \cos= 1$, for $x$ big enough you have
$$
1 - \frac 12 <\cos\frac 1x\le 1+\frac 12
$$